# How to get notified of updates to public maven repositories for new plugins?

Tags: maven-2, repository

Are there any tools which will notifiy you automatically of any new plugin additions from public maven repositories (e.g. Apache | Codehaus | JBoss | Sourceforge maven repository ...)

Comment: Related gradle-themed question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23905439/give-a-warning-when-a-dependency-is-outdated-in-gradle

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## *Maven Versions Plugin*

Not an automatic solution but you can use the [*Maven Versions Plugin*](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) has a [`versions:display-plugin-updates`](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/display-plugin-updates-mojo.html) goal that *will check all the plugins and reports used in your project and display a list of those plugins with newer versions available*. Here is [an example](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/display-plugin-updates.html) of the output it produces:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Unnamed - org.codehaus.mojo.versions-maven-plugin.it:parent:pom:2.0
[INFO]    task-segment: [versions:display-plugin-updates]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [versions:display-plugin-updates]
[INFO]
[INFO] The following plugin updates are available:
[INFO]   maven-checkstyle-plugin .................................. 2.1 -> 2.2
[INFO]   maven-clean-plugin ....................................... 2.1 -> 2.2
[INFO]   maven-deploy-plugin ...................................... 2.3 -> 2.4
[INFO]   maven-javadoc-plugin ..................................... 2.4 -> 2.5
[INFO]   maven-site-plugin .......................... 2.0-beta-6 -> 2.0-beta-7
[INFO]
[WARNING] The following plugins do not have their version specified:
[WARNING]   maven-compiler-plugin ..................... (from super-pom) 2.0.2
[WARNING]   maven-deploy-plugin ......................... (from super-pom) 2.3
[WARNING]   maven-install-plugin ........................ (from super-pom) 2.2
[WARNING]   maven-javadoc-plugin ........................ (from super-pom) 2.4
[WARNING]   maven-site-plugin .................... (from super-pom) 2.0-beta-6
[WARNING]   org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin .................. 1.2
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: < 1 second
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Sep 01 15:55:18 IST 2008
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/104M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It can also be used to produce [a report](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/dependency-updates-report-mojo.html) (part of the site) that you could for example generate each night.

---

> I was not necessarily looking for updates on the libraries used in my project, but was interested in obtaining regular updates on certain products which I am interested in.

For this, the best option might be to subscribe to the relevant mailing lists (by mail or RSS) and to track announcements.

Comment: I was not necessarily looking for updates on the libraries used in my project, but was interested in obtaining regular updates on certain products which I am interested in. Maybe the workaround would be to have a build file and list all those dependencies

Answer (score 32):

There is now an excellent site: https://www.artifact-listener.org/

Comment: Unfortunately, the site no longer seems to be up. But the author's code is opensourced at https://github.com/openwide-java/artifact-listener

Comment: The site is up and I have been using it for a long time. Works great.

Comment: It seems that the site is no longer maintained and accessible (certificate is expired)

Comment: There are no issues with the certificate at the moment and it looks like they are using a Letsencrypt certificate which is being renewed automatically

Comment: The project is now officially [unmaintained](https://github.com/openwide-java/artifact-listener/commit/ba6eaf2c75ae8e96d27ebccd1e8a28c4d3621dc9)